# Question about expanding a vector form of covariance of two r.v

Tags: covariance

I am trying to proof why the two lines of the following expression are equal. I found it in one of the books on machine learning

$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}[\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}]
&= \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}\bigl[
\{\mathbf{x} - \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}{[\mathbf{x}]}\}
\{\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}} - \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{y}}\{\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}]\}
\bigr] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}\bigl[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}\bigr]
- \mathbb{E}{[\mathbf{x}]}\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}].
\end{align}
$$

If I expand the first line, the cross terms disappear. It is not explained in the book, so I tried to work it out by myself. Here's the approach:

$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}[\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}]
&= \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}\bigl[
\{\mathbf{x} - \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}{[\mathbf{x}]}\}
\{\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}} - \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{y}}\{\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}]\}
\bigr] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}\bigl[
\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}
- \mathbf{x}\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{y}}[\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}]
- \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}[\mathbf{x}]\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}
+ \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}{[\mathbf{x}]}\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{y}}{[\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}]}
\bigr]  \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}\bigl[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}\bigr]
- \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}\bigl[\mathbf{x}\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{y}}[\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}]\bigr]
- \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}\bigl[\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}[\mathbf{x}]\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}\bigr]
+ \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}\bigl[\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}{[\mathbf{x}]}\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{y}}{[\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}]}\bigr] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}\bigl[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}\bigr]
- \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}\bigl[\mathbf{x}\bigr]\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{y}}[\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}]
- \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}[\mathbf{x}]\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{y}}\bigl[\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}\bigr]
+ \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}{[\mathbf{x}]}\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{y}}{[\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}]} \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}\bigl[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}\bigr]
- \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}{[\mathbf{x}]}\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{y}}[\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}].
\end{align}
$$

I understand expectation of a constant is the constant itself. Hence, exp. from another expectation is the expectation. I am not 100% sure about each middle term, s.a.

$$
\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}\bigl[\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}[\mathbf{x}]\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}\bigr]\ \equiv\ \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}[\mathbf{x}]\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{y}}\bigl[\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}\bigr]\quad\text{or simply}\quad\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}]\mathbb{E}\bigl[\mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}\bigr]
$$

If that is not correct, I wonder what makes the first expression true?

Thanks.